# Issue installing Netbeans in Windows 10: Java SE Development Kit (JDK) was not found on this computer

Tags: java, netbeans, java-8, java-7

I'm trying to install the TMC Netbeans version on Windows 10. I'm getting this error:

Java SE Development Kit (JDK) was not found on this computer

JDK 7 is required for installing Netbeans with TMC 1.1.8. Make sure that the JDK is properly installed and run installer again. You can specify valid JDK location using --javahome installer argument.

I got the same error using the regular version of Netbeans. I know it is installed correctly because I got IntelliJ to work just fine. How do I fix this issue? I've been searching for answers, but I haven't found anything for Windows 10?

Also, I have JDK 9 installed.

Comment: I tried the command line with this command and it didn't work:  tmc-netbeans_mooc_tmcbeans-windows.exe --javahome "C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9"

Comment: tmc-netbeans_mooc_tmcbeans-windows.exe --jdkhome "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9" was also unsuccessful and I got the same error

Comment: I tried this:

tmc-netbeans_mooc_tmcbeans-windows.exe --javahome "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9" --jrehome "C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9"

and got this:

There is no JRE at specified location C:\Program Files\J 
I'm so confused. Can anyoneplease shed some light? I'm giving up for now.

Comment: so did you solve it? this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49502600/how-can-i-install-netbeans-with-jdk-10

Answer (score 10):

Download and install jdk-8u181.exe for Netbeans 8.2 to install properly. Its a requirement under the Netbeans 8.2 installation instructions

Netbeans with JDK

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-netbeans-jsp-3413139-esa.html

Comment: thank you ,your link really helped and it worked.

Answer (score 7):

Open cmd > Change directory to wherever your netbeans executable installer is present > type **{*name of the netbeans executable installer*}.exe --javahome"C:\Program Files\Java\{*name of the jdk folder*}**

This worked for me.

Comment: **`java runtime evnironment (JRE) was not found`**

found this error

Answer (score 4):

Took me some time to overcome this. This is what I did:
1.During installation of JDK change the path from jdk-9.x.x to jdk
2.open netbeans installer location in command prompt and type:
**netbeans.exe --javahome "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk"**

Answer (score 2):

Just install java 8. because java 10 is not work properly with netbeans

Comment: kindly consider adding more information and reasons in your answers

Comment: Works for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you setting Environment variables for java wrong. You should check Environment variables for java installation

JAVAHOME : `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4`

path : `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\bin`

Answer (score 0):

On Win10 I tried this and it works:
1. jdk-8u181-windows-x64.exe
2. netbeans-8.2-windows.exe
This works.
Else, with JDK 10, I got everytime the error message listed in this Topic.

Answer (score 0):

Just install java 8. Because java 10 is not work properly with netbeans.
Download and install `jdk-8u181.exe` for Netbeans 8.2 to install properly.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error. 
I downloaded the netbeans IDE then downloaded the JDK, still had the error.
I restarted my computer and tried the installer again and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

1. Download and install: 
   a.  jdk-10.0.2_windows-x64_bin; 
   b.  jre-8u181-windows-x64
   c.  netbeans-8.2-windows.