# Netbeans 9 C++ Support

Tags: c++, netbeans, netbeans-9

I wonder if there is a support for C++ in Netbeans 9. [This link](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/index.html) shows C++ on screenshot (when creating new project). However, after installing, I don't have one.

Comment: On Apache Netbeans 11.1 (the current version) the Tools > Plugins > Settings actually contains na unchecked by default checkbox to enable 8.2 plugins. Enable it, Change check for updates frequency to: After restart, and restart the IDE. The C++ plugin would now appear in the list of available plugins.

Answer (score 35):

> I wonder if there is a support for C++ in NetBeans 9.

The answer to that is definitely no, and definitely yes...

- No, in the sense that the use of C++ on NetBeans 9 is not currently supported by Apache, and it is done at your own risk. NetBeans is currently being handed over from Oracle to Apache, and they haven't got to the C/C++ part yet. See [What's Happened to My Favorite NetBeans Plugins?](https://blogs.apache.org/netbeans/entry/what-s-happened-to-my) for more information.
- Yes, in the sense that it is technically feasible to do it; the NetBeans 9 IDE allows you to use C/C++.

This is what you need to do:

**Step 1 of 2: Make C/C++ available as a plugin.**

- **Tools > Plugins > Settings** tab **>** click the **Add** button.
- On the **Update Center Customizer** screen:

  - Enter some value in the **Name** field (e.g. *"My plugins"*),
  - Enter http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/8.2/uc/final/distribution/catalog.xml.gz in the **URL** field
  - Click the **OK** button.
- This should create a new entry in the **Configuration of Update Centers** list in the **Settings** tab.
- Checking that new entry should instantly add plugins to the **Available Plugins** tab.
- Click the **Available Plugins** tab, then click the **Category** column to sort the entries by category.
- The **Name** of the entry at the top of the list should be **C/C++**. If so, you have successfully made the plugin available:

  [image: availablePlugins]

**Step 2 of 2: Install the C/C++ plugin.**

- Check the **C/C++** entry shown in the screen shot above, and then click the **Install** button.
- Follow the wizard's instructions. The plugin will be downloaded and installed, and you will be required to restart NetBeans.
- To confirm that **C/C++** has been installed, click **Tools > Plugins > **Installed** tab. You should see an entry for the **C/C++** plugin you just installed.
- Also, verify that you can now create a **C/C++** project through the Project wizard:

  [image: C++Project]

Notes:

- The finer details on configuring C/C++ on NetBeans 9 (**Tools > Options > C/C++**) are unchanged from NetBeans 8.x. Refer to [Configuring NetBeans IDE 8.0 for C/C++/Fortran](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/80/cpp-setup-instructions.html) for that.
- Much of this answer has been copied from an answer I gave on [problems with Tomcat on NetBeans 9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51567033/2985643), but the details are sufficiently different to merit a separate answer.

Comment: Is this as stable in 9.0 as it was under the previous version where it was officially supported?

Comment: @Gili I can't really answer that since I have only done simple "Hello world!" testing in C++ on NetBeans 9.0. One way to get a feel for the stability might be to skim through the [Jira Bug Reports for C++ on NetBeans 9.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-371?jql=project%20%3D%20NETBEANS%20AND%20status%20%3D%20Open%20AND%20affectedVersion%20%3D%209.0%20AND%20text%20~%20%22C%2B%2B%22). There aren't that many new issues, but that may reflect a relatively small number of C++ users on 9.0 at present rather than the true absence of new bugs.

Comment: What bothers me is that this information was so hard to find I had to look it up on stackoverflow. What bothers me even more is that apache has screenshots that show netbeans 9 listing to create a new C++ project, I really consider that false advertising. Url for reference: https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/

Comment: @come You have a point. It's not unreasonable for NetBeans 8.x users to assume that NetBeans 9 will continue to support C++. While the NB90 web site does not explicitly claim that it does, I think it would have been appropriate to be very clear about the absence of formal support. Formal support for C++ will be included in a future NB release.

Comment: The maintainers at Apache risk not getting users as soon as they might and a useful project dying- no one who has already been bitten by missing features is going to risk more time moving if they think they might suddenly find themselves without a feature they expect to be there and moving back again: they should list the feature sets of 8.2 v current side by side PROMINENTLY . And make the community more accessible eg like stackexchange as opposed to all that TLDR/Doesn't Work email palava.

Comment: @Bob No argument from me, and I made a similar point in my comment above. It's fine for the NetBeans team to post _"What's new in NetBeans x.y"_ but they really should also prominently post _"What's **changed** in NetBeans x.y"_ and _"What's **been removed** in NetBeans x.y"_. You shouldn't have to go to blogs, YouTube videos or SO to find such fundamental and important information.

Answer (score 17):

**Netbeans 10 and 11** - adding C / C++ also works in the same fashion.

In Netbeans go to **Tools->Plugins->Settings**

Entry **NetBeans 8.2 Plugin Portal** is already present.

Click the checkbox next to this entry.

Switch to **Available Plugins** tab, click **Check for Newest**.

C / C++ is now on the list.

Computer that this is done is on Windows 10 x64.

Comment: This also seems to work in netbeans 11.0 LTS. My testing of it is only basic.

Comment: What about configuring it ? The link [Configuring NetBeans IDE 8.0 for C/C++/Fortran](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/80/cpp-setup-instructions.html) is dead ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install C++ plugin (Tools -> Plugins)

[image]

Comment: Hm, on one machine I have no plugins available to download but on work machine  everything is ok.

Comment: Make sure you can access: http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/dev/uc/final/main/catalog.xml.gz

Comment: netbeans support for c++ is very poor especially in the context of C++17 new language features  and so does the Eclipse CDT  , consider investing  in Jetbrains Clions to gain productivity for cross compilation

Comment: Alternatively to Clions you may want to consider the free Android Studio, that has C++ support.