# How to make NetBeans IDE 9 work with PHP?

Tags: php, netbeans, netbeans-9

How to make NetBeans IDE 9 work with PHP?

I finally installed NetBeans IDE 9. Thanks to another stackoverflow question. [How to install Netbeans 9 on Windows simple way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52305299/how-to-install-netbeans-9-on-windows-simple-way/53696939#53696939)

Only to discover that it works only with Java

[image]

How to make it work with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution for this question is similar to that for the question [Netbeans 9 C++ Support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51493882/2985643). The details differ but the overall approach to follow is the same.

**Step 1 of 2: Make PHP features available as plugins.**

- **Tools > Plugins > Settings** tab > click the **Add** button.
- On the **Update Center Customizer** screen:

  - Enter some value in the **Name** field (e.g. "*NetBeans PHP Plugin*"),
  - Enter    http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/8.2/uc/final/distribution/catalog.xml.gz
    in the **URL** field

    [image: GetPhp]
  - Click the **OK** button.
- This should create a new entry in the **Configuration of Update Centers** list in the
  **Settings** tab.
- Checking that new entry should instantly add plugins to the **Available Plugins** tab.
- Click the **Available Plugins** tab, then enter *PHP* in the **Filter** field to list the PHP plugins:

  [image: listPhp]

**Step 2 of 2: Install the PHP plugins.**

- Check the PHP plugins in the screen shot above that you want to install, and then click the **Install** button.
- Follow the wizard's instructions. The plugins will be downloaded and installed, and you will be required to restart NetBeans.

To confirm that the plugins have been been installed, click **Tools > Options**. You should see a new entry for PHP which allows you to configure it:

[image: OptionsPHP]

The wizards for creating PHP projects will now be available under **File > New Project...**

[image: phpProject]

Notes:

- The use of PHP on NetBeans 9 is not officially supported, and it is done at your own risk.
- PHP is pre-installed on NetBeans 10, which will be released shortly. You can download a [beta version of the latest Jenkins build of NetBeans 10 as a zip file](https://builds.apache.org/job/incubator-netbeans-linux/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/nbbuild/) which works on all platforms. You will need to activate PHP when you use the Project Wizard to create a PHP project for the first time:

  [image: activatePhp]

Comment: Thanks. NetBeans 10 is comming? I did not know that.