# Netbeans and JDK 10

Tags: java, netbeans

I have been using Netbeans upto 8.2 for several years. But now I have installed JDK 10 and was forced to migrate to Eclipse. But I do not feel very comfortable. I would like to go back to Netbeans.

Does Netbeans support JDK version 10 now? I mean July, 2018.

Comment: Did you try or read the docs? And if the docs are old (which seems to be the case) then that's an indicator that Netbeans might be dead.

Comment: Netbeans 9 supports JDK 10: https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/

Comment: I did some more research for you (a simple Google query for "netbeans 9") and one of the first results is this page where it states "Java 9 and 10 support": https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/ - edit: seems like assylias did the same simple google search ;)

Comment: NetBeans was given to the Apache Software Foundation when Java 9 was released. On July 29, 2018 Apache released NetBeans version 9.0 which has support for Java 9 and 10.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, NetBeans supports Java 10, but there are several important caveats to be aware of:

- NetBeans 8.2 does not support Java 10. It just won't work.
- [NetBeans 9 supports Java 10](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/index.html). It was released yesterday (July 29, 2018).
- NetBeans 9 only officially supports Java SE. Some options (plugins) available on NetBeans 8.2 are not provided on NetBeans 9 by default, such as Java EE and C/C++. However, there is a way to add those options (at your own risk). See [this answer to **How to get Netbeans 9 to deploy a valid webapp on Tomcat**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51567033/2985643) for details. Also see [What's Happened to My Favorite NetBeans Plugins?](https://blogs.apache.org/netbeans/entry/what-s-happened-to-my)

Notes:

- NetBeans 8.2 is an Oracle product, but they are in the process of handing the NetBeans components over to Apache, and NetBeans 9 comes from Apache. The transition explains why many plugins are not available in the initial release of NetBeans 9, but they will become available in coming releases.
- [The NetBeans 9 download](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/index.html) is in the form of a single zip file for all operating systems. Just unzip to a folder, then locate and run **netbeans64.exe** (or **netbeans.exe** for 32-bit).

---

*Updated to add further notes:*

- You can safely install and run NetBeans 8.2 and NetBeans 9 concurrently.
- The default platform for NetBeans 9 is still Java 8. You must explicitly add **JDK 10** as a platform: **Tools > Java Platforms > Add Platform...**
- To create a Java 10 project, open the project's properties and ensure that the following are set:

  - **Properties > Libraries > Java Platform:** *JDK 10*
  - **Properties > Sources > Source/Binary Format:** *JDK 10*
- An easy way to verify that **JDK 10** is set up correctly is to create a trivial Java application and put this code in the `main()` method: `var v = 123; System.out.println("v=" + v);` If that compiles and runs you are fine (and vice versa).

Comment: Netbeans 9 opens but there seems to be lots of problems. I was able to set up Netbeans TOOLS>JAVA PLATFORM and PROJECT>PROPERTIES>JAVAPLATFORM......

Comment: That doesn't sound good, but I can run a Java 10 Web application on Tomcat 9.0.10 using NetBeans 9 (the latest version). Can you clarify the specific problem(s) you are getting, or update your post? Also, see if any relevant errors are in the NetBeans Log (**View > IDE Log**).

Comment: Hi Skomisa,
I am not even trying to develop a WEB application. It is a single user DESKTOP application which was developed on JAVAFX in Netbeans 8.2. My JRE is 10.0.2 while JDK is 10.0.1. I am not an expert in JAVA, for that matter anything. :) Just because I wanted to add AUTOCOMPLETION with my Combo Boxes,  I had to move to JDK 10, (because some post said that). And then forced to install ECLIPSE. Now NETBEANS 9 is released as of July end. Should I mention anything about JRE in any SYSTEM Variable of in JAVA CONSOLE ? Please let me know. Thanks, Gold

Comment: @HornigoldArthur No, you don't need to set any system (environment) variables, nor specify your JRE, when using NetBeans 9. As long as you have added JDK 10 to Java Platforms, and set the properties of your project to use Java 10, you should be fine. So can you update your post (or open a new question) to detail the specific problem(s) you have when using NetBeans 9? You can check the NetBeans log (**View > IDE Log**) if you are getting unexpected errors.

Comment: I installed 10.0.2 and reinstalled netbeans 9. It appears to be working... I haven't started any serious work. That is a great relief. (Prelude to other headaches, I Suppose. :) )

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans 9 started working for me after I moved to JDK 10.0.2 instead of 10.0.1 ..... may be it will help guys who are struggling like me.

Enjoy.