# Netbeans not opening in ubuntu 18

Tags: java, netbeans, ubuntu-18.04

When I click 'NetBeans' it doesn't open... no error nothing.

Tried running 'netbeans' in terminal and error

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.netbeans.ProxyURLStreamHandlerFactory (file:/usr/share/netbeans/platform18/lib/boot.jar) to field java.net.URL.handler
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.netbeans.ProxyURLStreamHandlerFactory
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Tried reinstalling - first removing

```
sudo apt-get purge netbeans
```

then reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get install netbeans
```

But it's the same error.

```
java -version
openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.1, mixed mode)
```

Not sure how to fix this. Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Netbeans 8.2 and earlier do not support JDK 10. You can see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51599463/2796463 for details. To use Netbeans, you will need to install JDK 8 (openjdk-8-jdk).

If you want to continue using JDK 10 for other software and JDK 8 for netbeans, then you can modify the `netbeans_jdkhome` variable inside the file <NetbeansRoot>/etc/netbeans.conf. On my system NetbeansRoot is /usr/share/netbeans, but I do not know if it is the same on Ubuntu.