# Can not add Hibernate platform in Apache Netbeans IDE 9.0

Tags: hibernate, netbeans-9

I've installed Apache Netbeans 9.0 Incubator on linux mint
I'm working on Hibernate but this newly installed IDE doesn't provide Hibernate or even Java EE platform.

I download jboss tools and add in Netbeans Platform but it doesn't work.
I think it is for Eclipse IDE not for Netbeans IDE.

How can I add Hibernate platform in Netbeans IDE 9.0 ?

Comment: You need to install some plugins to enable Hibernate and Java EE in NetBeans 9.0. Please see the [second half of my answer to an unrelated question about NetBeans 9.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51567033/2985643) for details on how to do that.