# Java SE Development Kit (JDK) was not found on this computer

Tags: java, netbeans

I am new in java and I want to install netbean recently I have install `jdk-10.0.2_windows-x64_bin` and `netbeans-8.2-windows` too. I have successfully install `jdk` and the file path is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2`. when I install `netbean` it throw an error mention below in image:

[image]

I have also use the following command in cmd but it show error i.e. `The system cannot find the path specified` and the command mention below:

```
C:\Users\admin>\Downloads\netbeans-8.2-windows.exe --javahome "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2"
```

So, How can I fix it and install netbean on my system? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Once you say * I have install jdk-10.0.2_windows-x64_bin and netbeans-8.2-windows too*, and then you say *when I install netbean it throw an error mention below in image*! Please clarify what have you done! Also, the JDK being asked as shown in the error message is too old!.

Comment: You need to [download and install NetBeans 9](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/) in order to use JDK 10 with NetBeans.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know netbeans 8.2 does not support JDK 10.

You can either use netbeans 9 (google that) or use a previous JDK like 8.

Source: [How can I install Netbeans with JDK 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49502600/how-can-i-install-netbeans-with-jdk-10)

Comment: You should not create an answer that merely links to another answer on Stack Overflow. Provide that information as a comment instead.

Comment: I would have added a comment instead of an answer, but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set environment variable **PATH** C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Kerlos Bekhit's answer, you must used Java versions that are between 8 and 5. The latest version of java that netbeans supports is `Java SE 8`.

Here is the direct download link to Java SE 8 on oracle's webpage: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

If you are interested to see more about versions of java netbeans accepts read this documentation article on netbeans' site: 
https://netbeans.org/community/releases/82/relnotes.html

Also **IMPORTANT** if you want to keep both versions of java installed, be sure to **CHANGE** the file path to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-8u181...\bin`

Answer (score 0):

java jdk 10 is having an issue with netbeans installation. uninstall it and install java jdk 8 this should resolve the problem. 
if it doesnt work,
follow through this:[JDK was not found on the computer for netbeans 6.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079472/jdk-was-not-found-on-the-computer-for-netbeans-6-5)

Answer (score 0):

Same issue. All of this is not working fo me. But downloading and installing JRE - is working.