# gradle in netbeans build failed, could not execute build using Gradle installation

Tags: java, gradle, netbeans, cmd

Trying to setup a project to work with Spring MVC and google maps APIs in NetBeans 8.2(JDK 1.9.0) via Gradle.

Maybe it´s not a great mix but bear with me here please.

1. I downloaded [this gradle release](https://gradle.org/next-steps/?version=4.10.2&format=bin) and copied it inside C:\Gradle, ending up with: "C:\Gradle\gradle-4.10.2\bin"
2. I set the java variables according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26640589/4770813)
3. I downloaded the [google-maps-services-java](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java) library to use the API
4. I fired up oldie goody NetBeans and downloaded the Gradle plugin
5. I created a Gradle project and setup the **Gradle Installation Directory** and **Gradle user home directory** options, under **Miscellaneous\Gradle**, to: ***C:\Gradle\gradle-4.10.2***

So far so good.

When I try to build the brand new project it fails and the first line in the stacktrace reads

*org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not execute build using Gradle installation 'C:\Gradle\gradle-4.10.2'*

which, I'll say, looks pretty self-explanatory but, why is that installation not working is beyond me.

(I'll include stacktrace if needed).

Then, just to see if I could get more hints, I tried `gradle` in the console (Windows 10, I can imagine the shudders), and was greeted with:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at
https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Unrecognized option: --add-opens
```

So far, every google search I try with the stacktrace line directs me to android targeted issues and if I try the console output well, nothing useful yet.

Insights appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

`gradle --version` outputs:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.10.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-09-19 18:10:15 UTC
Revision:     b4d8d5d170bb4ba516e88d7fe5647e2323d791dd

Kotlin DSL:   1.0-rc-6
Kotlin:       1.2.61
Groovy:       2.4.15
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.11 compiled on March 23 2018
JVM:          1.9.0-ea (Oracle Corporation 25.0-b62)
OS:           Windows 8.1 6.3 amd64
```

**IN THE END**

**This is more a *why it happened* than a *solution***

Finally, it narrowed down to incompatibility between **Gradle 4.10.2** and **JDK 9**, so I tried with **JDK 11** just to learn it does not come with a public JRE so no. After that it was **JDK 10** which did not get along with **NetBeans 8.2**, apparently [this is why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49502998/4770813). Then, I looked for NetBeans 9 only to find another obstacle: [it currently does not support PHP, Javascript, C/C++ projects which I also need, only Java SE at the moment](https://blogs.apache.org/netbeans/entry/what-s-happened-to-my).

All of this, just to land right where I started, JDK 9. Only way forward now is using an older Gradle or sticking with Maven, darn. Advice still appreciated.

Comment: so where does `--add-opens` come from?

Comment: @ScaryWombat; beats me :). This is a fresh build, meaning I have not included any code in any config file whatsoever. also, just in case, when I tried to look for *gradle.properties*, I actually found 7 of them, all inside the *samples* folder

Comment: Having a quick `google` it seems that `--add-opens` is a java9 runtime flag, which JDK are you using? and what version is supported by your library

Comment: well, I'm using (according to NetBeans's *Tools\Java Platforms*) JDK 9. As to what version is supported by gradle 4.10, I really don't know.@ScaryWombat; one more thing: I just tried to `java --version` in *cmd* and it throws `Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion' has value '1.9', but '1.8' is required. Error: could not find java.dll. Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.`

Comment: @ScaryWombat; Do you think I should find a newer version of Gradle? is there a newer version? I think there is a 4.10.3 RC but I don't think that would be any better nor I know where to download it from. Also, I said I installed the Gradle plugin via Netbeans' *Plugins* wizard, but now if I try and go there again I can't see Gradle in the **Installed** tab, nor in any other tab for that matter, odd.

Comment: Can you post the output of `gradle --version`?

Comment: @Bernie; updated

Comment: Thanks, I thought your Gradle might have been using JDK 8, but looks ok. Although - is that an early access version of the JDK? Maybe there's a later JDK 9 version that would work.

Comment: @ScaryWombat; please read my last update. thanx for the help

Comment: @Bernie; please read my last update. thanx for the help

Comment: @Scaramouche The error you got when executing `java -version` shows your JVM installation is wrong. Have you cleaned up any old JDK installations from the `PATH` variable? `JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: to answer your question: yes, I have installed/uninstalled several JDK versions and set env vars accordingly to no avail, but please refer to the final segment of the question for a description, thanks @LittleSanti